# Display image in mat with jframe (OpenCV 3.00)

Tags: java, swing, opencv, image-processing

How to display Mat image in `JFrame`. `SetIcon()` does not accept mat parameter. Image should be used in `OpenCV 3.00` before displaying. But OpenCV can only open mat images. Is there some way to convert image?

```java
public void displayImage()
{            
    Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread(getClass().getResource("lena.png").getPath());

    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());           
    JLabel lbl=new JLabel();
    lbl.setIcon(image);
    frame.add(lbl);       
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
```

I did find code to convert it but it has `highgui` which is no longer in OpenCV 3.00.

```java
MatOfByte byteMat = new MatOfByte();
Highgui.imencode(".bmp", mat, byteMat);
return new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteMat.toArray()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert the Mat to a BufferedImage, then draw it on a Panel, Canvas or similar:

```
public static BufferedImage bufferedImage(Mat m) {
    int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
    if ( m.channels() > 1 ) {
        type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
    }
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(m.cols(),m.rows(), type);
    m.get(0,0,((DataBufferByte)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData()); // get all the pixels
    return image;
}
```